# AWS lambda sequentially invoke same function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have nearly 1000 items in my DB. I have to run the same operation on each item. The issue is that this is a third party service that has a 1 second rate limit for each operation. Until now, I was able to do the entire thing inside a lambda function. It is now getting close to the 15 minute (900 second) timeout limit.

I was wondering what the best way for splitting this would be. Can I dump each item (or batches of items) into SQS and have a lambda function process them sequentially? But from what I understood, this isn't the recommended way to do this as I can't delay invocations sufficiently long. Or I would have to call lambda within a lambda, which also sounds weird.

Is AWS Step Functions the way to go here? I haven't used that service yet, so I was wondering if there are other options too. I am also using the serverless framework for doing this if it is of any significance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods you mentioned are options that would work.  Within lambda you could add a delay (sleep) after one item has been processed and then trigger another lambda invocation following the delay.  You'll be paying for that dead time, of course, if you use this approach, so step functions may be a more elegant solution.  One lambda can certainly invoke another--even invoking itself.  If you invoke the next lambda asynchronously, then the initial function will finish while the newly-invoked function starts to run.  This [article on Asynchronous invocation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html) will be useful for that approach.  Essentially, each lambda invocation would be responsible for processing one item, delaying sufficiently to accommodate the service limit, and then invoking the next item.

If anything goes wrong you'd want to build appropriate exception handling so a problem with one item either halts the rest or allows the rest of the chain to continue, depending on what is appropriate for your use case.

**Step Functions** would also work well to handle this use case.  With options like [Wait](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html) and using a loop you could achieve the same result.  For example, your step function flow could invoke one lambda that processes an item and returns the next item, then it could next run a wait step, then process the next item and so on until you reach the end.  You could use a [Map](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html) that runs a lambda task and a wait task:

> The Map state ("Type": "Map") can be used to run a set of steps for
> each element of an input array. While the Parallel state executes
> multiple branches of steps using the same input, a Map state will
> execute the same steps for multiple entries of an array in the state
> input.

This [article on Iterating a Loop Using Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-create-iterate-pattern-section.html) is also useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the messages to be processed serially and are happy to dump the messages to sqs, set both the **concurency** of the lambda and the **batchsize** property of the sqs event that triggers the function to **1**

Make it a FIFO queue so that messages dont potentially get processed more than once if that is important.